# Coded-UI: Test Explorer and HTML Log treat multiple Test Method failures differently

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, assertions

First and foremost similar questions are posted by other users but this question is little different as it has multiple Test Methods.

As per the following approach; I have placed only **1 assertion per Test Method** simply because, Coded-UI will ignore rest of the test execution of a Test Method upon an assertion failure.

In the following code (Calculator) as you can see I have 2 Test Methods. Each Test Method will have 1 assertion. If assertions in both Test Methods fail, You will see both the failures under the **Test Explorer** view with the reason.

Now the issue is this, if you click the **UITestActionLog.html** links for both Test Methods you will see that, only the assertion failure in the **CodedUITestMethod1()** has logged in the HTML report (Refer **Assert_1_Failed.PNG**).

But the assertion failure in the **CodedUITestMethod2()** has not logged in the HTML report even when **Test Explorer** clearly displays the assertion failure (Refer **Assert_2_Failed.PNG**). That report will contain actions until the assertion call. (Basically someone looks at the 2nd HTML report will think **CodedUITestMethod2()** is fine as its full of green).

Can someone tell me how I could display the failed assertion of the 2nd Test Method too on the HTML report? Or is this a Microsoft bug? (Surely I cannot create a Coded-UI project per assertion?)

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    this.UIMap.Press_1();
    this.UIMap.Press_Add();
    this.UIMap.Press_2();
    this.UIMap.Press_Equals();
    this.UIMap.Assert_Add();            
}

[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod2()
{
    this.UIMap.Press_2();
    this.UIMap.Press_Substarct();
    this.UIMap.Press_1();
    this.UIMap.Press_Equals();            
    this.UIMap.Assert_Substract();            
}
```

[image: Assert_1_Failed.PNG]

[image: Assert_2_Failed.PNG]